# Find an integer quartic root of a $3\times 3$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, canonical-transformation

> Find a $3 \times 3 $ matrix $X$ with integer coefficients such that
>   \begin{align*}
> X^{4} &= 3
> \begin{bmatrix}
> 2 &-1 &-1 \\
> -1 &2 &-1 \\
> -1 &-1 &2 
> \end{bmatrix}.
> \end{align*}

**My attempt.** Let us consider the matrix 
\begin{align*}
A &= 3
\begin{bmatrix}
2 &-1 &-1 \\
-1 &2 &-1 \\
-1 &-1 &2 
\end{bmatrix} \\
&= \begin{bmatrix}
6 &-3 &-3 \\
-3 &6 &-3 \\
-3 &-3 &6 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
Calculate the roots of characteristic polynomial, i.e calculate the eigenspace $AZ=\lambda Z$, this is given for the equation system $A-\lambda I=0$, where $I$ is $3 \times 3$ identity matrix. 
\begin{align*}
\begin{vmatrix}
6-\lambda & -3 & -3 \\
-3 & 6-\lambda & -3 \\
-3 & -3 & 6-\lambda
\end{vmatrix} &= -\lambda \left( \lambda-9\right)^{2}
\end{align*}
Therefore, the polynomial function, the zero $\lambda=9$ has multiplicity $2$, and $\lambda=0$ has multiplicity $1$ and these special values are called the eigenvalues of the matrix $A$.

We need to know the dimension of the eigenspace generated by this eigenvalue. Thus, solve the system $\left(A-3I\right)Z=0$ where $Z^{T}=\left(x,y,z \right)$ in order to find the eigenvectors. 
(1) For $\lambda =0$, then $\left(A-3I\right)Z=0Z$. Thus, $x=y=z=0$. Hence, $v_{1}= \left(1,1,1\right)^{T}$ is an eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda=0$.

(2) For $\lambda=9$. Then, we choose $x=0$, $y=1$, then $z=-1$. Hence, $v_{2}= \left(0,1,-1\right)^{T}$. Also, choose $x=1$, $y=-1$, then $z=0$, hence, $v_{3}= \left(1,-1,0\right)^{T}$. Furthermore, $v_{2}$ and $v_{3}$ are eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda=9$.

Thus, we have the matrix $S=\left[v_{1} \ v_{2} \ v_{3} \right]$. Then, 
\begin{align*}
S &= 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 &0 &1 \\
1 &1 &-1 \\
1 &-1 &0 
\end{bmatrix} 
\end{align*}
and its inverse 
\begin{align*}
S^{-1} &= 
\begin{bmatrix}
1/3 & 1/3 & 1/3 \\
1/3 & 1/3 & -2/3 \\
2/3 & -1/3 & -1/3 
\end{bmatrix} 
\end{align*}
Thus, $A=SJS^{-1}$, where 
\begin{align*}
J &= 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 &0 &0 \\
0 &9 &0 \\
0 &0 &9 
\end{bmatrix} 
\end{align*}
where $J$ is the Jordan canonical form of $A$. Hence, $\displaystyle X=SJ^{1/4} S^{-1}$
\begin{align*}
X&=SJ^{1/4}S^{-1} \\
A &= 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 &0 &1 \\
1 &1 &-1 \\
1 &-1 &0 
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 &0 &0 \\
0 &9^{1/4} &0 \\
0 &0 &9^{1/4} 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1/3 & 1/3 & 1/3 \\
1/3 & 1/3 & -2/3 \\
2/3 & -1/3 & -1/3 
\end{bmatrix}\\
\end{align*}
Now, $9^{1/4}= \sqrt[]{3}, \ - \ \sqrt[]{3}, \ \sqrt[]{3} \ i$, and $\ - \ \sqrt[]{3} \ i$. All these four values can be utilized, for $9^{1/4}$ and accordingly values of $X$ can be changed. All combination can be calculated to find the values of $X$.

\begin{align*}
X&=SJ^{1/4}S^{-1} \\
A &= 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 &0 &1 \\
1 &1 &-1 \\
1 &-1 &0 
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 &0 &0 \\
0 &\sqrt[]{3} &0 \\
0 &0 &\sqrt[]{3} 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1/3 & 1/3 & 1/3 \\
1/3 & 1/3 & -2/3 \\
2/3 & -1/3 & -1/3 
\end{bmatrix}\\
&=\begin{bmatrix}
2/\sqrt[]{3} & -1/\sqrt[]{3} & -1/\sqrt[]{3} \\
-1/\sqrt[]{3} & 2/\sqrt[]{3} & -1/\sqrt[]{3} \\
-1/\sqrt[]{3} & -1/\sqrt[]{3} & 2/\sqrt[]{3}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
X&=SJ^{1/4}S^{-1} \\
A &= 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 &0 &1 \\
1 &1 &-1 \\
1 &-1 &0 
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 &0 &0 \\
0 &- \ \sqrt[]{3} &0 \\
0 &0 &- \ \sqrt[]{3} 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1/3 & 1/3 & 1/3 \\
1/3 & 1/3 & -2/3 \\
2/3 & -1/3 & -1/3 
\end{bmatrix}\\
&=\begin{bmatrix}
-2/\sqrt[]{3} & 1/\sqrt[]{3} & 1/\sqrt[]{3} \\
1/\sqrt[]{3} & -2/\sqrt[]{3} & 1/\sqrt[]{3} \\
1/\sqrt[]{3} & 1/\sqrt[]{3} & -2/\sqrt[]{3}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
X&=SJ^{1/4}S^{-1} \\
A &= 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 &0 &1 \\
1 &1 &-1 \\
1 &-1 &0 
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 &0 &0 \\
0 &\sqrt[]{3} \ i &0 \\
0 &0 & \sqrt[]{3} \ i
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1/3 & 1/3 & 1/3 \\
1/3 & 1/3 & -2/3 \\
2/3 & -1/3 & -1/3 
\end{bmatrix}\\
&=\begin{bmatrix}
2i/\sqrt[]{3} & -i/\sqrt[]{3} & -i/\sqrt[]{3} \\
-i/\sqrt[]{3} & 2i/\sqrt[]{3} &-i/\sqrt[]{3} \\
-i/\sqrt[]{3} & -i/\sqrt[]{3} & 2i/\sqrt[]{3}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
X&=SJ^{1/4}S^{-1} \\
A &= 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 &0 &1 \\
1 &1 &-1 \\
1 &-1 &0 
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 &0 &0 \\
0 &  - \ \sqrt[]{3} \ i &0 \\
0 &0 &  - \ \sqrt[]{3} \ i
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1/3 & 1/3 & 1/3 \\
1/3 & 1/3 & -2/3 \\
2/3 & -1/3 & -1/3 
\end{bmatrix}\\
&=\begin{bmatrix}
-2i/\sqrt[]{3} & i/\sqrt[]{3} & i/\sqrt[]{3} \\
i/\sqrt[]{3} & -2i/\sqrt[]{3} &i/\sqrt[]{3} \\
i/\sqrt[]{3} & i/\sqrt[]{3} & -2i/\sqrt[]{3}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

However, you can see that non of $X$'s have integer coefficients. Any idea where I have messed up something! Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Even if it is the case, I am still getting this $$ \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{-2}{\sqrt{3}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \\
\sqrt[]{3} & 0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \\
\frac{-1}{\sqrt{3}} &\frac{-1}{\sqrt{3}} & \frac{-2}{\sqrt{3}}
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: I tried $A^2=9A$, so $A^4=3^4A$, but $X$ is not a scalar multiple of $A$ (unfortunately), this would have been too easy.

Comment: You messed up because a matrix can have infinitely many $k$-th roots (e.g. $I_2=\pmatrix{1&t\\ 0&-1}^2$ for **every** $t$), but you have tried only the diagonal ones.

Answer (score 2):

An idea is to find a matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\0&a&b\\0&c&d\end{pmatrix}$ which would

1. give $\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\0&3&0\\0&0&3\end{pmatrix}$ when being squared;
2. have integer elements after being multiplied by $\begin{pmatrix}1/3&1/3&1/3\\1/3&1/3&-2/3\\2/3&-1/3&-1/3\end{pmatrix}$.

These statements lead to the following conditions for $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$:
\begin{align}
a^2+bc&=3,\\
b(a+d)&=0,\\
c(a+d)&=0,\\
d^2+bc&=3,\\
a+2b&=0 \mod 3,\\
a-b&=0 \mod 3,\\
c+2d&=0 \mod 3,\\
c-d&=0 \mod 3.
\end{align}
If $a+d\ne0$ then $b=c=0$, and the matrix is diagonal, so it has to contain square roots of $3$. So, $a+d=0$. Trying some small values for the unknowns, I came up with $a=2$, $d=-2$, $b=-1$, $c=1$. Finally, the matrix $X$ is
$$
X=SAS^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}-1&1&0\\1&0&-1\\0&-1&1\end{pmatrix}.
$$

The matrix $X$ isn't unique. There are quite a few steps which can be done differently. First, instead of $\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\0&3&0\\0&0&3\end{pmatrix}$ one can use any matrix which square equals $\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\0&9&0\\0&0&9\end{pmatrix}$, for example $\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\0&-3&0\\0&0&-3\end{pmatrix}$ (just make sure it has the two eigenvalues of the same sign, otherwise you wouln'd be able to find the square root of it). Second, the condition 2 is a bit too strict. You'd want matrix $SAS^{-1}$ to be integer, and integrality of $AS^{-1}$ is a sufficient condition for that (in general it isn't necessary, though for our case it is). Third, there are multiple solutions for $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ even for the listed case. For example, $a=4$, $d=-4$, $b=13$, $c=-1$.

Comment: [+1] very interesting deduction.

Comment: Thank you so much! Would it be the only value of $X$?

Comment: @AhmadTalafha: I've added a few words on uniqueness of $X$.

Comment: @SergeiGolovan Thank you so much! On last question, may I know how to did you come up with these conditions for $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$:
$$\begin{align}
a^2+bc&=3,\\
b(a+d)&=0,\\
c(a+d)&=0,\\
d^2+bc&=3,\\
a+2b&=0 \mod 3,\\
a-b&=0 \mod 3,\\
c+2d&=0 \mod 3,\\
c-d&=0 \mod 3.
\end{align}$$

Comment: @AhmadTalafha: First four of them came from equating the square of $A$ to $\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\0&3&0\\0&0&3\end{pmatrix}$. The last four are obtained by expressing $AS^{-1}$ via $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ and requiring the  matrix elements to be integral.

Answer (score -1):

Here is another approach. Let $E_k$ be the $k\times k$ matrix of ones. We are going to find all integer matrix solutions of $X^4=A:=3(3I_3-E_3)$.

The eigenvalues of $A$ are $0,9,9$. Therefore $X$ has a simple eigenvalue $0$ and $\pm\sqrt{3},\pm i\sqrt{3}$ are the only possible nonzero eigenvalues of $X$. However, as the characteristic polynomial of $X$ has integer coefficients, the spectrum of $X$ must be $\{0,\sqrt{3},-\sqrt{3}\}$ or $\{0,i\sqrt{3},-i\sqrt{3}\}$.

The characteristic polynomial of $X$ is therefore $x^3\pm3x$. Hence $X^3=\pm3X$ and $3(3I_3-E_3)=A=X^4=\pm3X^2$. Consequently, we must have
$$
X^2=\pm(3I_3-E_3).\tag{1}
$$
As $X$ must share the same null space as $X^4=3I_3-E_3$, all row sums and column sums of $X$ are zero. Therefore, if we define $e=(1,1)^T$, $X$ must be in the form of
$$
X=\pmatrix{P&-Pe\\ -e^TP&e^TPe}.\tag{2}
$$
for some $2\times2$ matrix $P$. So, we need to solve
$$
X^2=\pmatrix{P(I_2+E_2)P&-P(I_2+E_2)Pe\\ -e^TP(I_2+E_2)P&e^TP(I_2+E_2)Pe}
=\pm(3I_3-E_3)=\pm\pmatrix{3I_2-E_2&-e\\ -e^T&2}.
$$
This boils down to solving $P(I+E)P = \pm(3I_2-E)$, i.e.
$$
P\pmatrix{2&1\\ 1&2}P=\pm\pmatrix{2&-1\\ -1&2}.\tag{3}
$$
At this point, we can already obtain an obvious solution $P=\operatorname{diag}(1,-1)$, which translates back to
$$
X=\pmatrix{1&0&-1\\ 0&-1&1\\ -1&1&0},\tag{4}
$$
but we shall continue our search for other solutions. Note that the two constant matrices in $(3)$ have identical eigenspaces, so it's a good idea to perform a change of basis. Let $L=\pmatrix{1&1\\ 1&-1}$. Then $L^{-1}=L/2$. If we define $Q=\pmatrix{a&b\\ c&d}:=LPL^{-1}$, then
$$
P=L^{-1}QL
=\frac12\pmatrix{a+b+c+d&a-b+c-d\\ a+b-(c+d)&a-b-(c-d)}.\tag{5}
$$
By considering the values of $(1,\pm1)P(1,\pm1)^T$, we see that if $P$ is an integer matrix, $a,b,c,d$ must be integers, and if $a,b,c,d$ are integers, $P$ is an integer matrix if and only if $a+b+c+d$ is even. Also, by conjugation by $L$ on both sides of $(3)$, we get
$$
Q\pmatrix{3&0\\ 0&1}Q=\pmatrix{3a^2+bc&(3a+d)b\\ (3a+d)c&3bc+d^2}=\pm\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&3}.\tag{6}
$$
Therefore, all solutions to $(3)$ are given by all integers $a,b,c,d$ such that
\begin{cases}
a+b+c+d\text{ is even},\\
3a^2+bc=\pm1,\\
3a+d=0.
\end{cases}
As $3a+d=0$, the condition that $a+b+c+d$ is even can be further reduced to that $b+c$ is even. Hence $b$ and $c$ have the same parity. In summary, all integer matrix solutions to $(3)$ and hence to $(1)$ are given by integers $a,b,c,d$ such that
\begin{cases}
bc=\pm1-3a^2,\\
b,c \text{ have the same parity},\\
d=-3a.
\end{cases}

Comment: $X^2=E_3-3I_3$ would work too (here $0$ and $\pm i\sqrt3$ are the eigenvalues of $X$).

Comment: @SergeiGolovan Thanks. Now fixed.